# Display one piece of HTML content but select another that is more accessible?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, user-experience

We have a duplication issue while selecting content that contains a screen reader block, such as the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/dowbuabr/1/

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="screen-reader">2 squared</div>
  <div class="display" aria-hidden="true">2^2</div>
</div>
```

```css
.screen-reader {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

By using `aria-hidden`, we're able to indicate to screen readers that the second content block is for display purposes and should not be read out loud. However, when highlighting the entire block and using a tool like Google Chrome's speak command, both blocks are spoken.

[image: Highlighting the content block actually selects both pieces, not just the one that doesn't specify aria-hidden is true]

Is there a best practice for specifying that the first piece of content should be selected when the content block is highlighted? Using `user-select: none` doesn't feel right because it doesn't highlight the block if we want to copy it, and even though it technically solves the problem, it's a UX concern if we're highlighting a hidden block. See the following screenshot, which is "correct" but doesn't look right because there's no visual cue that we've highlighted the right thing.

https://jsfiddle.net/dowbuabr/2/

[image: Good result but no highlighting on the content block]

Comment: I have little experience with screen readers and even more so with people that actually actively use them but text-selection sounds very rare to me (unless the screen reader does that the user) and in the rare event it does happen "2^2" is probably understandable. As an actual answer maybe you could use `<div aria-label="2 squared">2^2</div>`

Comment: This example has been simplified intentionally--our content is actually fairly complicated in these cases. :( Assume that the content could be a paragraph in length, and significantly different visually than what you'd want to express audibly.

Comment: Conundrum. I was already afraid you were going to say that. You can't really change what's selected without annoying your non-TTS users unless you can figure out if someone is relying on TTS. Without the actual use case I'm just going to just suggest 2 random things: 1. Ask if user is using TTS. 2. Allow users that use TTS (or all) to "see" the TTS-representation next to the regular. I'm sure there is some way that everyone can be happy with (except for maybe the design department)

Comment: Did you try `speak: none` along with `aria-hidden`?

Comment: Hm. Just realised that even though I saw that prop in some frameworks, it never made it as a W3C Recommendation. Maybe it never worked anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `pointer-events` css property.

The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible.

```css
.avoid-clicks {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: rgba(51,51,51,0.85);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 4em;
  padding: 0.75em;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1.4 "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  padding: 3em;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

p {
  padding: 0.75em;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some basic flow content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni eos ipsum sunt repellat nisi modi voluptatum ipsa eligendi minima cumque. Accusantium laudantium autem quae earum eaque expedita quia molestiae in.</p>

<div class="avoid-clicks">try selecting text through me</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to solve a different problem. We only want to highlight  the content that isn't removed by `aria-hidden`.